# Generating function for non-linear recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

What will be the generating function for recurrence relation of following type

$f(n)$ = $f(n/2)$ + $n^2$

please help

Comment: Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

*Suppose* than
$$f(n)=a+b n+c n^2$$ So
$$f(n)-f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-n^2=0 \implies \frac{b }{2}n+\frac{3 c }{4}n^2-n^2=0$$ Make all coefficients equal to $0$.

If you are not convinced, try
$$f(n)=a+b n+c n^2+dn^3$$
$$f(n)-f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-n^2=0 \implies \frac{b }{2}n+\frac{3 c }{4}n^2-n^2+\frac {7 d} 8n^3=0$$ Make all coefficients equal to $0$.